# A lot of bandwidth for a lower price than AWS?

Tags: bandwidth

I'm going to be serving up a lot of audio content and am looking for something cheaper than Amazon's $0.15/GB. I don't really need a cdn since latency, speed and so on don't matter too much. Is there anything a bit cheaper?

Comment: This is ultimately a [Shopping Question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) and as such is being closed as Too Localised.

Answer (score 1):

If a dedicated server will do, have you looked at providers like [100TB.com](http://www.100tb.com)?

Comment: That seems awfully cheap...are they overselling?

Comment: So, one is too expensive, the other one too cheap ...

Comment: @SvenW - there was an extended question on here about 18 months ago about providers like 100TB being "too cheap" so yes, there is such a thing. I can't find the link to it at the moment though unfortunately.

Comment: @sf77 I'm sure they are overselling to a certain extent, but we've never had any problems, and tons of others haven't either. Same people have though, so I suggest doing lots of research first: http://www.webhostingtalk.com/search.php?searchid=30449607

Comment: More and more providers are claiming to offer 100TB+ dedicated servers. Here is a post listing most/all of them: http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=1033574&highlight=100tb

Answer (score 0):

I've used and have been happy with [iWeb](http://iweb.com/) in Montreal for years who offer 10TB/month on all dedicated servers. Low end servers start around 70-100$/month. I also see they have a 20TB special on their "Smart" servers (dedicated/virtualized/cloud server).